# How to set the diagnostic level for neovim lsp

Tags: vimrc, neovim, lsp, lunarvim

By default the lsp has set the diagnosticLevel to Hints, i wanna set this to information level. I tried looking at various places but couldn't find much.

I am using LunarVim config if that gives extra context

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Since you're using neovim, you might want to take a look at the lsp api (I think it's documented somewhere)—I don't know for sure, but I would bet money that's where you can configure such a thing

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if LunarVim has a layer on top, but the minimal setup in Lua would be:

```lua
vim.lsp.handlers["textDocument/publishDiagnostics"] = vim.lsp.with(
  vim.lsp.diagnostic.on_publish_diagnostics, {
    signs = {
      severity_limit = "Hint",
    },
    virtual_text = {
      severity_limit = "Warning",
    },
  }
)
```

As you can see, you can hide the virtual text and keep the signs (which I think should be the default). There are more things you can configure, have a look at `:h on_publish_diagnostics`